# PHP nested loops of different lengths

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

i have two arrays:

```
$Array1 = array (1,3,4,6,8);
$Array2 = array (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
```

I want to compare both the array. If the data in array1 and array2 have the same value, then I want to show "sama", and otherwise "tidak sama".

so later the result like this.

```
1 sama, 2 tidak sama, 3 sama, 4 sama, 5 tidak sama, 6 sama, 7 tidak sama, 8 sama, 9 tidak sama
```

I've tried to make it like this:

```
<?php
    $array1 = array(1,3,4,6,8);
    $array2 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

    $a = array();

    for ($i=0; $i < count($array2) ; $i++) { 
        for ($x=0; $x < count($array1); $x++) {  
            if ($array1[$x] == $array2[$i]) {
                $a[$i] = $i." sama"; 
            } else {
                $a[$i] = $i." gak sama";
            }
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($a);
?>
```

but the result is like this:

```
["0 gak sama","1 gak sama","2 gak sama","3 gak sama","4 gak sama","5 gak sama","6 gak sama","7 sama","8 gak sama"]
```

So, what should I do? Thanks

Comment: Here's an another hint: fill $a with "gak sama" and remove else statement

Comment: The question is ambiguous. In `2 tidak sama`, "2" is the value from `$array2` or its position in the array (starting from 1)? From the expected output I'll assume it is the value but in the code you print positions (that start from 0, not from 1). Another issue: what happens if a value is present in `$array1` but it is not present in `$array2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use build in functions like [array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) and [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php).

```
$array1 = array(1,3,4,6,8);
$array2 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

$intersection = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
$diff = array_diff($array2, $array1);

$result = array();
foreach ($intersection as $value) {
    $result[$value] = $value . ' sama';
}
foreach ($diff as $value) {
    $result[$value] = $value . ' tidak sama';
}
ksort($result);

echo implode(', ', $result);
```

http://rextester.com/QHSV17063

Answer (score 2):

It's nice that you tried to do it. Although there are more efficient ways to do it, the problem with your code is that you overwrite `$a[N]` over and over again. To solve the problem, just add a `break` statement.

```
$a[$i] = $i." sama"; 
break; // add this
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually reduce the loops and use `in_array` function to check for presence of element in second array.

```
    $a = array();

    for ($i=0; $i < count($array2); $i++) {
        $j = $i + 1;
        if (in_array($array2[$i], $array1, true)) {
            $a[$i] = $j . " sama";  
        } else {
            $a[$i] = $j . " gak sama";
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($a);
?>
```

Comment: I think this is what answers the OP questions more appropriately...

Comment: Also worthy of note that it is performance wise  you  `count()` outside the `for` statement. e.g `$array2Count = count($array2);      for ($i=0; $i <`$array2Count ; $i++) `

  >Since the size never changes, the loop be easily optimized by using an intermediate variable to store the size instead of repeatedly calling Count
Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a nested loop, and for your desired output you must also check if the corresponding item is present in the shorter array.

```
<?php
    $array1 = array(1,3,4,6,8);
    $array2 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

    $a = array();

    for ($i=0; $i < count($array2) ; $i++) { 
        if (isset($array1[$i]) && $array1[$i] == $array2[$i]) {
            $a[$i] = ($i + 1)." sama"; 
        } else {
            $a[$i] = ($i + 1)." tidak sama";
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($a);
?>
```

Output:

`["1 sama","2 tidak sama","3 tidak sama","4 tidak sama","5 tidak sama","6 tidak sama","7 tidak sama","8 tidak sama","9 tidak sama"]`